# String to char* conversion fails for non static string

Tags: c++, string

Note : The API uses char* and not const char * so I cannot use c_str() also the function call sendCall is an Aysnchronous call

Below is my code it works fine when I use

```
char* payloadString = >&currString[0];
```

however when I try using

```
char* payloadString = &secondCopy[0];
```

It fails and I am not able to able to understand the reason. I want to create a dynamically updateable string like desiredString in below code which takes version variable and assign it to a static string secondCopy and be able to use that instead of currString but I guess I am making some mistake with address of operator by using a modified static string. Please suggest a work around.

```
void functionName()
{
    std::string version;
    version = "ABC";
    static std::string  currString= "<Version=\"3.0\" Ret=\"false\"/>";
    std::string desiredstring= "<Version="+version+" Ret=\"false\"/>";
    static std::string secondCopy = desiredstring;
    char* payloadString = &currString[0];
    //char* payloadString = &secondCopy[0];

    XDSC::Definition aDefinition("sname", "sid");

    try
    {
            std::auto_ptr<otf::ClientSession> aSession;
            aSession = getResources()->getManager().getSession("XML");
            aSession->setAttachedToServerConversation(true);
            aSession->setLogicalName("xyz");
            aSession->setITOReturnPackage("svrc");
            boost::shared_ptr<Payload> aPayload = boost::make_shared<Payload>(aDefinition, "3.0",payloadString, strlen(payloadString));
            sendCall(aSession.get(), aPayload,"SRING", true);

    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        throw (exception(ERROR,"SendCall Failed to Send"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `secondCopy.c_str()`? Does the API only take a `char *` and not a `const char *`?

Comment: I tried using c_str() but it returns a const char *  and the below function needs a char *  instead and not a const char *

Comment: Don't know if it is a problem or just a side note, but your two version strings (besides `3.0` vs `ABC`) are not the same. `currString` has quotes around the value and `desiredString` does not.

Comment: Also... "it fails" is not a sufficient explanation of what happens.

Comment: Is `sendCall` asynchronous? If so, then any function local variables will go out of scope while it is still executing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Do you get a compiler error or access violation at run time or wrong string?

Comment: yes sendcall is an Asynchronous call

Answer (score 2):

Even if  `secondCopy` is `static` (just like `curString`), you are assigning to it a local variable every time you call `functionName`. This means that the underlying pointer to the `char*` inside the `string` object may change between two calls to the function. If the `sendCall` function is asynchronous or if you save the pointer somewhere for later use, you may find it invalid if you called the function another time.

Example:

```
char* foo(string s)
{
    static string ss = "aaa";
    ss = s; //assignment operator, the char* inside the string class may be reallocated
    char* pointer = &ss[0];
    return pointer;
}

void main()
{
    string s1 = "a";
    char* p1 = foo(s1); //p1 is OK for now
    string s2 = "b";
    char p2* = foo(s2); //p1 is probably NOT OK

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ere running in paralell the `sendCall` function:

```
sendCall(aSession.get(), aPayload,"SRING", true);
```

`aPayload` become from `payloadString` and `payloadString` become 
from `&currString[0];` (is recommended to use `c_str()` member function, THIS NO SOLVE
YOU PROBLEM HERE) so when `functionName` is going out of the scope the `currString` variable automatically call his destructor and 
`char* payloadString = &currString[0];` become as an invalid pointer.

Comment: If is use this char* payloadString = &currString[0];  it works fine ...sendCall fails when I try doing this char* payloadString = &desiredString[0]; or char* payloadString = &sendCopy[0]; which I don't understand as both are static strings